# USB install of Ubuntu 18.04 server, UART issue

Tags: server, 18.04, system-installation, intel, serial-port

When the U18.04 installer loads onto system, its kernel lacks DMA driver for the 8250 UART device, and no interactive console messages are visible, so I cannot complete the installation. The missing UART DMA as a root cause was discovered when tried different distros on same system, where it all went well. How can I add a driver to installer image? System is Intel Atom P5000 SOC. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to install a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system?   It was named 18.04 because it was released in 2018-April (ie. a *year.month* format is used) and had 5 years of *standard* support; ie. is supported until 2023-April.  Why install a system that's got mere days of *standard* support left?

Comment: Thank you, @guiverc. The reason for choosing 18.04 LTS server is because it is the base version of a distro of a customer of ours, who wishes to integrate its application / product on our Intel Atom P5000 platform. This is in fact a smart NIC with Atom cores on it, and an integrated legacy 8250 UART device. I'm not sure if later LTS release would behave differently. Will try to verify.